# VHDL - 10% Duty Cycle

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, duty-cycle

I need to generate 500Hz from 50MHz clock frequency. I already got it. My problem here is how should the code to be adjusted if I want to change the duty cycle to 10%?

Thank you.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity FreqDivider500Hz is
port(
    clock   : in STD_LOGIC; -- 50 Mhz
    clear   : in STD_LOGIC;
      freq1 : out STD_LOGIC
);
end FreqDivider500Hz;

architecture Behavioral of FreqDivider500Hz is
signal adjfreq: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";
signal adjclock : std_logic := '0';

begin

freq1 <= adjclock;

countClock: process(clock,clear)
begin
    if (clear = '1') then
        adjfreq <= "0000000000000000";
    elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then
        -- Flip a the output once every 50,000 cycles (1kHz)
        -- to give a 500Hz output with 50% duty cycle
        if (adjfreq = "1100001101010000") then  
            adjfreq <= "0000000000000000";
                if adjclock <= '0' then
                adjclock <= '1';
                else adjclock <= '0';
                end if;
            else 
            adjfreq <= adjfreq+1;   
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: First, throw away the non-standard library and use numeric_std (or plain old ranged integer subtypes). Then, throw away all those magic numbers...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have different delays depending on whether the output is currently high or low.

So rather than having 50000 cycles high and 50000 cycles low you have 10000 cycles high and 90000 cycles low. This will require a bit of conditional logic and likely also a larger counter.

P.S. I think your current code actually has 50001 cycles high and 50001 cycles low, so it will actually give you slightly less than 500Hz.

P.P.S, It's often better to count down to zero than to count up to a defined value. Especially when the number of cycles you need to count is variable.

P.P.P.S your indentation seems messed up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it often better to count down than up? Is this a style choice or is there a performance difference?

Comment: It's not a big deal if the number of cycles you need to count is fixed but if it's variable (as it will be once the OP modifies his code) then comparing with zero is much simpler in logic terms than comparing with another variable. It does add a bit of complexity at the other side (loading the counter), but at least the FPGAs i've used recently have a "SLOAD" datapath which makes parallell-loading a variable value into a counter relatively cheap.

Comment: Yes, counting down is better, but to compare with zero is no good solution (this is the rule of thumb for CPUs). In hardware you are counting down to **-1**. This requires one additional bit in the counter (2s complement/signed counter) but no comparator is needed, because the counting end is inferred from the sign bit. There are also ways to improve up-counters by only comparing the ones in the value. This can be done if the counter never counts down. Note: If you count to -1 the init/reset value is `COUNTER_MAX - 2`.